# Why do I get invalid data in my CString formatted using Format()?

Tags: c++, string-formatting, cstring

```
LRESULT CFlashWnd::OnScannerProgress( WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    ScannerProgress *pEvent = (ScannerProgress *)wParam;

    CString scannerAreaText = _T("");
    scannerAreaText.Format(_T("<B>Scanning%3A</B> <font face='Arial' size='10'>%s</font>"), pEvent->pszScanner);

    CString scanProgressText = _T("");
    scanProgressText.Format(_T("<B>Scan Progress%3A</B> <font face='Arial' size='10'>%f</font>"), pEvent->dwScanPercent);

    CString scanProgressBarValue = _T("");
    scanProgressBarValue.Format(_T("%f%"), pEvent->dwScanPercent);

    if(pEvent->pszScanItem)
        free((void *)pEvent->pszScanItem);

    if(pEvent->pszScanner)
        free((void *)pEvent->pszScanner);

    delete pEvent;

    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting funky values and/or crashes. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but you should double check the %3A in your format strings. The percent sign, as you know, indicates a placeholder.

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing that crossed my mind. However there are not very many details on the website about escape characters while using Format().

Comment: I don't understand your reply. I think that's the problem. It should only take a second to remove that part and see if the problem goes away. If I'm not mistaken, %% can be used to indicate a single percent sign to the output.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of %3A, use %%3A.